# Does Electron ipcMain / ipcRenderer use sockets?

Tags: node.js, electron, ipc

### Context

I have a **sandboxed**, **context isolated**, Electron application with **node integration disabled** where I need to transfer image data from renderer to main process.

According to [this thread](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1948), passing large data array through Electron's own IPC system "got faster". But, I tried [node-ipc package](https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-ipc) with sockets and it is really fast. Unfortunately, using it in production would need the window to be run unsandboxed.

- **Electron**: 20.1.4
- **Node.js**: 16.13.2
- **OS**: macOS Monterey 12.6

### Question

This lead me to a question: **Does Electron uses Unix / Windows sockets for the inter-process communication?** If not: What is the underlying technology used?

While digging into [Electron's code](https://github.com/electron/electron), I can't find where `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer` are actually defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging in the Electron repo I see that the IPC is based on [Mojo](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/mojo/).

I failed to find any technical documentation on the transport part of Mojo. By digging into the code, I come to the conclusion that the underlying transport is platform-specific: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/mojo/+/refs/heads/main/core/channel_linux.cc https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/mojo/+/refs/heads/main/core/channel_mac.cc https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/mojo/+/refs/heads/main/core/channel_win.cc

So the Linux implementation looks like either shared memory or channels depending on the case, and the Mac implementation is based on Mach ports.